# Widget selection problem with rubberband in 2 layouts

Tags: python, pyside2

Currently, 2 layouts have been added, and buttons are added using FlowLayout at the top and below the label.
on Qrubberband

When the mouse is don't move, there is nothing wrong. When I drag, there is a problem with the selection.
Where did the problem come from?

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class QToolButton(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, label='', icon='', icon_size=100):
        super(QToolButton, self).__init__()
        self.label = label
        self.icon = icon
        self.icon_size = icon_size
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        self.setText(self.label)
        self.setIcon(QIcon(self.icon))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(self.icon_size, self.icon_size))
        self.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.ui()
        self.add_thumbnail()

    def ui(self):
        self.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        self.resize(1000, 800)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText('LABEL IMAGE')
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 100))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.flow_layout = FlowLayout()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.flow_layout)

    def add_thumbnail(self):
        for i in range(10):
            button = QToolButton(label='test', icon='test')
            self.flow_layout.addWidget(button)
            button.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
            self.origin = source.mapTo(self, event.pos())
        elif event.type() == event.MouseMove and event.buttons():
            if not self.rubberBand.isVisible():
                distance = (source.mapTo(self, event.pos()) - self.origin).manhattanLength()
                if distance > QApplication.startDragDistance():
                    if isinstance(source, QAbstractButton) and source.isDown():
                        source.setDown(False)
                    self.rubberBand.show()
            if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
                self.resizeRubberBand(source.mapTo(self, event.pos()))
                event.accept()
                return True
        elif event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease and self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.closeRubberBand()
            event.accept()
            return True
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def startRubberBand(self, pos):
        self.origin = pos
        self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
            QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def resizeRubberBand(self, pos):
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
                QRect(self.origin, pos).normalized())

    def closeRubberBand(self):
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.hide()
            selected = []
            rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
            for child in self.findChildren(QToolButton):
                if rect.intersects(child.geometry()):
                    selected.append(child)
            if selected:
                for i in selected:
                    if i.isChecked():
                        i.setChecked(False)
                    else:
                        i.setChecked(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.startRubberBand(event.pos())
        QMainWindow.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.resizeRubberBand(event.pos())
        QMainWindow.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.closeRubberBand()
        QMainWindow.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

class FlowLayout(QLayout):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, margin=0, spacing=-1):
        super(FlowLayout, self).__init__(parent)

        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)

        self.setSpacing(spacing)
        self.margin = margin

        # spaces between each item
        self.spaceX = 2
        self.spaceY = 2

        self.itemList = []

    def __del__(self):
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.itemList.append(item)

    def count(self):
        return len(self.itemList)

    def itemAt(self, index):
        if index >= 0 and index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList[index]

        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):
        if index >= 0 and index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList.pop(index)

        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):
        return Qt.Orientations(Qt.Orientation(0))

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        height = self.doLayout(QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        super(FlowLayout, self).setGeometry(rect)
        self.doLayout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):
        size = QSize()

        for item in self.itemList:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        size += QSize(2 * self.margin, 2 * self.margin)
        return size

    def doLayout(self, rect, testOnly):
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        lineHeight = 0

        for item in self.itemList:
            wid = item.widget()
            nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + self.spaceX
            if nextX - self.spaceX > rect.right() and lineHeight > 0:
                x = rect.x()
                y = y + lineHeight + self.spaceY
                nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + self.spaceX
                lineHeight = 0

            if not testOnly:
                item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = nextX
            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, item.sizeHint().height())

        return y + lineHeight - rect.y()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Where did the problem come from?

Comment: Can you please try to clarify the following sentence? "When the mouse is don't move, there is nothing wrong. When I drag, there is a problem with the selection." Also, what mouse button?

Answer (score -1):

When left-clicking the mouse, when it was mousePressEvent, it worked normally, and when it was mouseReleaseEvent, there was a problem with widget selection.
I have solved it now
the code is

```
def closeRubberBand(self):
    if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
        self.rubberBand.hide()
        selected = []
        rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
        for child in self.findChildren(QToolButton):
            if self.flow_layout_widget:
                layout_x = self.flow_layout_widget.pos().toTuple()[0]
                layout_y = self.flow_layout_widget.pos().toTuple()[1]
                child_w = child.geometry().size().toTuple()[0]
                child_h = child.geometry().size().toTuple()[1]
                cx, cy, cw, ch = (child.geometry().x() + layout_x, child.geometry().y() + layout_y, child_w, child_h)
                child_rect = QRect(cx, cy, cw, ch)
            else:
                child_rect = child.geometry()

            if rect.intersects(child_rect):
                selected.append(child)
        if selected:
            for i in selected:
                if i.isChecked():
                    i.setChecked(False)
                else:
                    i.setChecked(True)
```

Could there be an easier way?

Comment: Sorry but this answer is helpful. It might work for you, but anybody reading this would really understand what was the issue and how you actually solved it. For starters, the above code uses an attribute we know anything about (`self.flow_layout_widget`). Then, you didn't answer what I asked in my comment to your question; you wrote that again: "there was a problem"; then, **what** was the problem? Also, using `toTuple` is pointless in this way, just use `*.x()` and `*.y()`, or `*.width()` and `*.height()`, otherwise `x, y = object.pos().toTuple()` and `w, h = object.size().toTuple()`.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question to the community and my english is not good
The problem was that the widget was not selected well when left-clicking the mouse in mouseReleaseEvent.

Comment: I can understand that English is not your primary language, and nobody judges you about that. But consider that most of people here is in the same situation as yours; this means that most of them already have problems understanding correctly written *simple* English, which also means that those people will have major problems understanding *your* English. That's why it is important that you do all possible efforts to explain yourself as best as possible, **especially** if somebody asks you to do so as I did in my comment to your question. And believe me: my primary language is *not* English.

Comment: Now, to the point. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that the problem is that the widget(s) weren't correctly selected when *releasing* the left mouse button after the drag/select operation. Is it right? If that's the case, that is exactly what you should have answered to my comment (in which I specifically asked *what* mouse button you were pressing, BTW). That can be fixed, but, as said above, your answer doesn't provide a *valid* solution, mostly due to aspects we know *nothing* about: again, what is `flow_layout_widget`? Withouth that, **nobody** can understand your answer.

Comment: Okay. I will try my best to answer the question or question more accurately

Comment: I forgot to add a new variable
self.flow_layout_widget is simply QFrame()

self.frame = QFrame()
self.flow_layout_widget = self.frame

After dragging the mouse above the widget, release it, the widget is selected

So I got the position value of Qframe and added the Position value of the new self.findChildren(), so it was selected properly.

Comment: An empty frame? Placed where? And what's the point of having an empty frame in this case?

Comment: self.frame = Qframe()
self.flow_layout = FlowLayout()
self.frame.setLayout(self.flow_layout)

In the ui part, make the frame as above

I planned to put Toolbuttons in self.flow_layout later. :)

Comment: Answers should be self contained, and should also be helpful to others. If I (or anybody else) tries to put the above function in the original code, it would raise an exception and make the program crash. Please [edit] this answer and add all relevant modifications that allowed you to solve the problem so that anybody is able to apply them and run it.